# Open new page with h:commandButton in JSF page

Tags: jsf, payment-gateway, jsf-2.2, 2checkout

I want to open 2Checkout express payment form. I created this test code:

**JSF code:**

```
<h:form target="_blank" style="padding: 20px 20px 20px 20px;">
    <h:commandButton value="TwoCheckout" action="#{pricingCalculator.initTwoCheckout}" />
</h:form>
```

**CDI Bean:**

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class PricingCalculator implements Serializable {

    public String initTwoCheckout() throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("sid", "1817037");
        params.put("mode", "2CO");
        params.put("li_0_type", "product");
        params.put("li_0_name", "Example Product");
        params.put("li_0_price", "1.00");

        String message = TwocheckoutCharge.url(params);
        return message;
    }
}
```

I printed the output I get http link `https://www.2checkout.com/checkout/spurchase?mode=2CO&amp;li_0_price=1.00&amp;li_0_name=Example+Product&amp;sid=1817037&amp;li_0_type=product`

But when I press the `h:commandButton` the page is just refreshed in a new window. Can you tell me what is the proper way to open the return link using `h:commandButton`?

Comment: Totally not payment-gateway and 2checkout related. E.g. Try just putting a link to google in there. No difference...

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Anyway this simple example can be useful for someone.