# Generate http link for fast payment

Tags: braintree

I found this tutorial how to create page for payment s with Braintree

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+java/start/hello-server

I'm interested how I can generate link for express payment simmilar to PayPal express checkout using Java.

Comment: Your question isn't very clear. What does it mean to "generate link for express payment?"

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer at Braintree. You should checkout our [PayPal guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+java/guides/paypal/overview) to learn how to use our API to process PayPal payments.

If you have any questions, you should reach out to our [support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/) for further assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you show me how I can generate http link like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809414/open-new-page-with-hcommandbutton-in-jsf-page

Comment: We do not provide an integration method consisting of a single click payment link. Please contact our support team to get help integrating with Braintree using our [dropin](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/guides/drop-in) or [custom](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+ruby/guides/credit-cards) integration methods.